# Can't open Excel File created in R language

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

[image: screenshot of error message. The error message text is: "Compile error in hidden module: mdlGlobal. This error commonly occures when code is incompatible with the version, platform, or architecture of this application. Click "Help" for information on how to correct this error.]

I get the corruption error when I try to open the Excel workbook created in R.
I tried with both .xlsx and .xls extensions but neither worked!

The code that I used for doing all this is:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("RCreated.xls", create = TRUE);
saveWorkbook(wb)
createSheet(wb, name = "First")
```

HELP!

Comment: It'll be easier to diagnose the problem if you include the code you used to create the files.

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for that. I just added the code.. It's very basic though!

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't write a comma or tab delimited file using `write.csv` or `write.table`? These can be opened by Excel, and if you really need something in their format, you can then save it again as .xls/xlsx.

Comment: @Krishna Kanth The error indicates something related to the version/platform etc. Are you using latest version of the package (I guess it is XLConnect)?

Comment: @akrun Yes it is the latest version of the XLConnect pacakge... Just installed it.

Comment: Can you give us some simulated data we can test for ourselves? This question is hard to reproduce without the (corrupt) file.

Comment: Are you using 32/64 bit R? Are you using 32/64 bit Java? What versions of R, Java and Excel are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't you call the `saveWorkbook` *after* you do the manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

Create the sheet BEFORE saving the workbook.